# How to use fzf to search for directories only?

Tags: bash, fzf

Here is a use case: I use `fzf` to search for a list of directories, which then used with the `cd` command:

```
cd $(fzf)
```

However, the `fzf` command only displays files, not directories. Is there a way to instruct `fzf` to select only directories?

Comment: Use `find` fo find directories and pipe the output to `fzf`.

Comment: @larsks, this is a good work around. Please submit the answer and I'll give it points. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per my comment, you can generate a list of directories using `find`:

```
cd $(find . -type d -print | fzf)
```

You can adjust the `find` command to limit the depth of directories, or to only match directories with specific names, etc.

Generally, you're expected to use `fzf` as a filter, taking input from some external command.

Comment: With zsh globbing: cd $( ls -d **/*(/) | fzf --exact)

Comment: On Linux, piping the output of find into fzf is obvious. On Windows it is different. I frequently need  to search in Windows network shares with tens of thousands of files. Windows tools (Explorer and some command line "find" equivalent in Powershell) perform abysmally. I always though this had to do with the files being on the Net, but fzf burns through the entire hierarchy in seconds. However, I need to find directories, and fzf only gives me files.

Comment: How do you ignore specific folders like node_modules?

Comment: You could modify your `find` command (e.g., use the `-prune` option), or insert a `grep` into the pipeline to include/exclude paths.

Comment: I recommend looking into `fd` instead of `find`: https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Answer (score 1):

This example is in a unix system with zsh and assumes that all relevant files live in `~/code`, so please change the path accordingly based on your own file structure. The very first part of the command jumps to the relevant directory, so if you're not working from root make sure you change that first cd command from "~" to your own path as well.

To do a recursive DIRECTORY search in your main working dir (in this example, ~/code") from any pwd with fzf finder AND be able to jump to that directory automatically upon selection:

1. To run directly in bash `cd ~ && cd $(find ~/code -type d \( -name node_modules -o -name .git \) -prune -o -name '*' -type d   -print | fzf)`

Note that I'm filtering out all node_modules and .git directories. you can add to this by chaining `-o (or operator) -name dirToFilterOut`

2. Obviously you don't want to type this out every time you want to do a fuzzy dir search. Inside .zshrc, alias this command to a simple key binding. In this example, I'm using "f" so all I do is type "f" and enter in my shell to call this. Note that you have to escape some more characters inside .zshrc compared to when you write it directly in your terminal (this took the longest time to figure out) and don't forget to source the .zshrc file after you make the changes!

`alias f="cd ~ && cd \$(find ~/code -type d \( -name node_modules -o -name .git \) -prune -o -name '*'  -type d -print | fzf)"`